# Unicode character conversion with mixed values PHP/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, unicode

I'm getting values from a web service and the only information I've is that I've to to treat the data as 8 bit unsigned values. There are total 622 values in it and each value will be less than or equal to 255 '8 bit unsigned value'. I've to use these 622 values for y-axis of a graph, and the maximum value can be 255.
The input I'm getting is given below.

````
\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0002\u0002\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0004\u0004\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0006\u0006\u0007\u0007\u0007\b\b\t\t\t\n\n\u000b\u000b\f\f\f\r\r\u000e\u000e\u000e\u000f\u000f\u0010\u0010\u0010\u0011\u0011\u0012\u0012\u0012\u0013\u0013\u0014\u0014\u0015\u0015\u0015\u0016\u0016\u0017\u0017\u0017\u0018\u0018\u0019\u0019\u0019\u001a\u001a\u001b\u001b\u001b\u001c\u001c\u001d\u001d\u001d\u001e\u001e\u001f\u001f   !!\"\"\"##$$$%%&&&''(()))**+++,,---..///001122233444556667788899:::;;<<===>>???@@AAABBCCCDDEEFFFGGHHHIIJJJKKLLLMMNNNOOPPQQQRRSSSTTUUUVVWWWXXYYZZZ[[\\\\\\]]^^^__```aabbcccddeeeffggghhiiijjkkkllmmnnnoopppqqrrrsstttuuvvwwwxxyyyzz{{{||}}}~~�~~}}}||{{{zzyyyxxwwwvvuutttssrrrqqpppoonnnmmllkkkjjiiihhgggffeeeddcccbbaa```__^^^]]\\\\\\[[ZZZYYXXWWWVVUUUTTSSSRRQQQPPOONNNMMLLLKKJJJIIHHHGGFFFEEDDCCCBBAAA@@???>>===<<;;:::998887766655444332221100///..---,,+++**)))((''&&&%%$$$##\"\"\"!!   \u001f\u001f\u001e\u001e\u001d\u001d\u001d\u001c\u001c\u001b\u001b\u001b\u001a\u001a\u0019\u0019\u0019\u0018\u0018\u0017\u0017\u0017\u0016\u0016\u0015\u0015\u0015\u0014\u0014\u0013\u0013\u0012\u0012\u0012\u0011\u0011\u0010\u0010\u0010\u000f\u000f\u000e\u000e\u000e\r\r\f\f\f\u000b\u000b\n\n\t\t\t\b\b\u0007\u0007\u0007\u0006\u0006\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0004\u0004\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0002\u0002\u0001\u0001
````

First question is that do you think the values are in some consistent format? If so, what operations in PHP or Javascript I should do to convert these value?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Many of the characters are invalid in HTML (depending on HTML version, many control characters are prohibited), and it seems that they are not to be treated as characters at all but to be taken as integers in the range 0–255. So even if they appear in the `\u`nnnn notation, you should probably immediately convert them to integer values.

Comment: That is what I think, but how can I convert these to integers?

Comment: I've a converter here. http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ I get values converted from it, But I'm curious which one should i use for graph? If I go with decimal, one of the value I get 65533, that is more than 255. Which format should I keep in the converter for graph?

Comment: If you have been told them to be “8 bit unsigned values”, simply take the Unicode number as an integer and check that it is less than 256. Of course, there is not much you can meaningfully do with the values without information about their meaning.

Comment: But I think these are not all unicode numbers. Do you think the characters like }~~�~~} are unicode? I believe the whole data is invalid. Do you think?

Comment: All numbers in the range 0–255 are Unicode numbers. Characters “ }~~�~~}” are Unicode. But if you were told that the data is 8 bit unsigned values, why would you even try to consider them as characters? You should simply read the data as 8-bit quantities and interpret them as numbers 0–255, without even trying to interpret or render them as characters. I’m not sure what you mean by showing a string that starts with `\u0001`. That could mean a single value of 1, just rendered as `\u` notation, or six values.